# Run as different user

Tags: redhat, users, daemon

On a RedHat system, i'm trying to launch a program with a different user who dont have any shell. In /etc/passwd, shell is /sbin/nologin.

I have tried:

1. su myuser -c /home/myuser/script.sh
   Result: This account is currently not available.
2. With chown and setuid:
   chown myuser:mygroup /home/myuser/script.sh
   chmod +s /home/myuser/script.sh
   /home/myuser/script.sh
   Result: script.sh is still executed as my signed in user (root).

Comment: Are you running the `su` as root or an unprivileged user?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try:

```
su myuser -s /bin/sh -c /home/myuser/script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

this error means that in /etc/passwd you have set shell /sbin/nologin or /sbin/false for user myuser.

Please set something usefull like /bin/bash

Comment: That's what the OP already posted was happening; OP is asking if there's a way to run the program despite the username having no shell.

Comment: Yes... It is the question in fact. I would like to know if it is possible to run a script as a different user, without setting a shell in /etc/passwd

Comment: You can not do it using script if user have shell like this.